# Windows 7 has files that date back to 2009?

Tags: windows-7

So while I were looking at my PC's hard drive's contents, I noticed that there were files that had this specific date:
July 14th, 2009.

Can I safely assume that these files are what the Windows 7 setup copied to my hard drive? Or what are those files? The OS was installed to this PC in 2015.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite likely that the date on the files is actually the date that the Windows 7 installer archives were created by Microsoft.

Windows 7 [was released](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Windows+7+release+date) on July 22, 2009. That's a week and day after your file date.  I doubt that your copy of Windows was installed before Windows was released.

Answer (score 0):

Just because the file's meta info says so, doesn't mean that was the creation date (I can make a document right now that "was created" in 1975). The date is not as important as the files' paths (which it would help sharing) and, most importantly, contents.

Short Answer:
DO NOT delete anything you're not sure of, especially if it's in the "windows" folder. If you share the full file paths, perhaps you'd get a more useful answer.

Furthermore, I'd like to point out that the Windows 7 release date won't help if the system's clock was incorrectly set and there was no internet connection at the time of installation.

Comment: Who said anything about deleting them?